# How can settings for a WPA2 enterprise network be determined?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, netctl, wpa

Is it possible to inspect the output of some command to determine the right settings for a given WPA2 Enterprise wifi network? If so, how?

I've just been through the process of getting my university eduroam network set up using `netctl`. There seem to be a lot of `wpa_supplicant` options to be get just right, but most GUI clients seem able to autodetect these in many (if not all) cases. `wifi-menu`, on the other hand, doesn't work for WPA2 Enterprise.

I like the "Arch way" of text-based configuration but it would be good to be able to connect to work networks without having to ask for help from the IT department (when these things are trivial for other users).

Comment: The arch wiki had a page on [eduroam](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA2_Enterprise#netctl)

Comment: @Outurnate: it does, and I found it helpful, but it doesn't help understand what settings to use for an arbitrary network, and notes that even for eduroam you really need to ask your institution what settings to use.